# Enqueue a directory in audacious from nautilus right click

Tags: shell, ubuntu, enqueue

I am trying to make enqueue a directory in audacious. For that I want to make a shell script which will take the input I am giving as the directory to enqueue. `find . -iname \*.mp3 -print0 | xargs --null audacious --enqueue` this will enqueue all the files in the current directory. I want to make a shell script which takes the input for current directory.

Comment: ...and what problem are you having while trying to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "input" you're referring to command-line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec find "$@" -iname '*.mp3' -exec audacious --enqueue '{}' +
```

Comment: This works in terminal. I am using the shell script for command path in `nautilus-action`. But this also doesn't enqueue in gui.